# Why is cross domain AJAX prevented *if* you have no intention of evaluating the response as a script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, cross-domain

Let's say I want to use AJAX to retrieve a json file from an untrusted different domain.
I then parse the response as a javascript object without any script evaluation.
(A cookie is not sent with my request.)

I don't understand why the browser prevents me from doing this.

I understand that if I were to evaluate the response as a script then that would be a security issue.

I understand that there are work-arounds to achieve the above.

Is there a reason that my specific scenario should be prevented, or has it just got accidentally caught up in the same-origin dragnet?

Thanks.

(assuming the server does not support CORS)

Comment: So I came across this http://json.org/JSONRequest.html which is designed for precisely the use-case i describe. How come it has not garnered more support?

Comment: From w3 http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/: "JSONRequest has been considered by the Web Applications Working Group and the group has concluded that it does not meet the documented requirements. JSONRequest is a specific API and cannot handle e.g. cross-origin XSLT through <?xml-stylesheet?> or the same scenarios same-origin XMLHttpRequest can handle today in cross-origin fashion, e.g. manipulating resources making use of the REST architectural style." ???

Answer (score 3):

> ... you have no intention of evaluating the response as a script?

Firstly, browser security has no way of determining what you *intend to* do.

Second, the same source / origin restrictions are designed prevent other things as well: e.g. see 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx

Comment: can you elaborate on your second point please. Surely once you've given site 'X' your info then they can do what they like with it (regardless of any AJAX calls)?

Comment: @Pumbaa: interesting presentation but doesn't specifically answer my question.

Comment: sorry the link you pasted does not seem to answer my specific question.

Comment: @adam77 - the link explains that blocking your script from READING scripts from other sources protects the user against your script exploiting that information to do nasty things.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain AJAX is possible, but the remote server needs to support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and there may be certain header restrictions.

JSONP is not necessary for most applications. If the remote server does not support CORS, then you're stuck with the same-origin garbage and you'll have to use JSONP.

Note:

Older browsers don't support CORS.  You may want to use jQuery or a similar framework (I've had trouble with Mootools and cross-domain AJAX because I couldn't figure out how to remove some of the default headers.  jQuery worked out of the box for me on my set-up.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the questions. OP is not asking how to do it, but why it is not usually enabled.

Comment: Well, it IS enabled on the browser end on newer browsers... the only reason a request like that would fail is if the server doesn't support it or if the request headers are wrong.

Comment: Ok, then I stand corrected. Maybe it would help if you made it clearer that the OP's assumption is wrong. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: i added the CORS server assumption. aside: how is a decision made on the server meant to make the client any safer? in my specific scenario (untrusted server), what extra security do you get that you didn't have before?

Comment: If the server supports CORS, then you get the data as JSON and not as a script, so you can use JSON.stringify instead of eval (eval is a great way to break things as you probably know).  I don't know why cross-domain AJAX doesn't work by default, because it's much safer than the JSONP hack that we have to do to get around it.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at, allowing cross-origin requests seems to be safer than the workaround! i.e. JSONP requires a script evaluation whereas a straight cross-origin request can avoid that. CORS doesn't help if the server doesn't support it. Such a shame JSONRequest hasn't got off the ground.

Comment: I can kinda see where they're coming from... I mean, not all browsers support JSON.stringify (that is, if you consider IE to be a browser hehe), and when the standard come out for XMLHttpRequest, most browsers didn't support it.  They probably didn't think of the JSONP hack... it would have been much safer if they just included it as part of the spec to begin with...